# Where is the generated token in DJANGO stored during password reset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to access the generated token(in the database table) when I request the "forgotten password" functionality, but I cannot seem to find it.

I am using `django 1.10`, `rest_framework`, `django-rest-auth`. I have checked inside `authtoken_token` as well as inside `account_emailconfirmation` tables but was unsuccessfully.

In github the source code refers to this in python as `token_model` I think
https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/utils.py

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't store anywhere except user email. When user click on the provided link token parsed by [`PasswordResetTokenGenerator`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L8) to obtain timestamp. With this timestamp `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` generate NEW token. And compare this new token with provided by user, see [`check_token`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L23) method.

Comment: thank you for the reply. yes I realized this at the end. `from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator.make_token(user)` is used to generate a new token.